# Need explanation on Commanded EGR and ethanol%

Tags: fuel-system, obd-ii, egr, ethanol

There are 2 PIDs listed in [this Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs)  - Commanded EGR and ethanol%.

I have tried getting the values from some cars but have not succeeded. I am curious to know what do these 2 PIDs mean? Can someone please give a sample data set  (if you have) to get a taste of these 2 PIDs.

***Does that ethanol% PID tell what is the best ethanol% my fuel should have or what ethanol% is currently in my fuel?***

Comment: Ethanol PID is the cars best guess at the ethenol level is in the fuel. Commanded EGR is what the car wants the EGR valve position to be at, not all cars have electronic EGR valves some are simple vacuum deals.

Comment: @Ben   Throw that down as the answer.  It's short but it's legit.  If you have a link you can throw at dude too, all the better.   :-)  Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

Ethanol % PID is the cars best guess at the ethenol level is in the fuel. This is more common on E85 Vehicles.

Commanded EGR is what the car wants the EGR valve position to be at, not all cars have electronic EGR valves some are simple vacuum solenoids/diaphragms.

Happend to run into a truck with an electronic EGR setting a position code.
[image]

Working
[image]